# Keras: ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal (VGGNets)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Estou seguindo um [tutorial](https://youtu.be/7n1SpeudvAE) e carregado `modelo VGGNet16` pré-treinado using `Keras`

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
  model.add(layer)

model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predict'))
#model.summary()
```

Eu costumava `model.save('path/model_1.h5')` para salvar o modelo após o trem com `model.fit_generator(...)`

Então fiquei sem tempo em "Colaboratory". então eu queria usar `model = load_model('path/model_1.h5')` para recarregar meu modelo em vez de carregar mostrou como anteriormente com `vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()...`

E agora estou com este erro:

> ```
> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4096 and
> 1000. Shapes are [4096,10] and [1000,10]. for 'Assign_61' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [4096,10], [1000,10].
> ```

O que estou fazendo errado? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado ao povo de [@deeplizard](https://twitter.com/deeplizard) para me ajudar a encontrar esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482483/valueerror-when-loading-a-previously-saved-retrained-vgg16-model-using-keras) na versão em Inglês do StackOverflow.

Aqui a tradução:

O problema é com a linha `model.layers.pop ()`. quando usamos `.pop` para pular uma linha direta da camada `model.layers`, a topologia deste modelo não é atualizada adequadamente. Portanto, todas as operações a seguir serão ruins, nos dando uma definição errada do modelo.

Especificamente, quando adicionar um `camada model.add (camada)` `lista model.outputs` é atualizado para ser a camada tensor de saída. Você pode encontrar as seguintes linhas no código fonte de `Sequential.add ()`:

```
        output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
        # ... skipping irrelevant lines
        self.outputs = [output_tensor]
```

Quando `model.layers.pop` chamado, no entanto, não é `model.outputs` actualizados em conformidade, como resultado, a camada de recém-acrescentado irá ser chamada com um tensor de entrada mau (porque `self.outputs [0]` continua sendo a saída do tensor da camada removida).

Isso pode ser demonstrado com as seguintes linhas:

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.layers.pop()
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

print(model.layers[-1].input)
# => Tensor("predictions_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
# the new layer is called on a wrong input tensor

print(model.layers[-1].kernel)
# => <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1000, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
# the kernel shape is also wrong
```

O incorretamente `kernel` é porque estamos vendo o erro de arranjos de incompatibilidade de tamanho `[4096,3]` versus `[1000,3]`.

Para resolver este problema, simplesmente não adicione a última camada à sequência do modelo `Sequential`.

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
```

*Não falo português. Eu aprecio qualquer melhoria em escrever esta publicação para melhor compreensão.